# Problema con rutas relativas en PHP

Tags: php

No consigo que salgan por pantalla las imágenes del código. El resto del contenido sale bien y hasta donde sé las distintas partes de la web están correctamente escritas, por lo que entiendo que el problema tiene que estar en cómo estoy indicando las rutas a esas imágenes. La estructura de directorios es la siguiente:

- Carpeta_proyecto

  - imagenes (carpeta)
  - plantillas (carpeta)
  - el resto de archivos php de código

Aparte, me gustaría saber cómo hacer que estas ubicaciones sean eso, relativas, para que al pasar el proyecto a un servidor no tenga que ir cambiando todas las rutas.

```php
function cargar_datos(){
    //Carga de los datos
    $articulos = array(
        0 => array(
            "id" => 0,
            "titulo" => "Carcassonne",
            "a_imagen" => "imagenes/carcassonne.jpg"
        ),
        1 => array(
            "id" => 1,
            "titulo" => "¡Aventureros al tren!",
            "a_imagen" => "imagenes/aventureros.jpg"
        ),
        2 => array(
            "id" => 2,
            "titulo" => "Catan",
            "a_imagen" => "imagenes/catan.jpg"
        ),
        3 => array(
            "id" => 3,
            "titulo" => "Azul",
            "a_imagen" => "imagenes/azul.jpg"
        )
    );

    return $articulos;
}
```

Nota: añado el html que permite la salida del array

```
  <?php include "base.php" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<body>
    <h3>Catálogo</h3>
    <?php startblock("plantilla"); ?>
    <ul>
        <!--Muestra una lista de artículos-->    
        <?php
            foreach($articulos as $articulo){
        ?>
        <li>
            Artículo: <?php echo $articulo["id"] ?>
            <img src="<?php echo "imagenes/" .$articulo["a_imagen"] ?>"/>
            <h2><?php echo $articulo["titulo"]?></h2>
            <a href="http://localhost:3000/2%C2%BA/DWES/Unidad%205/Tarea%205/DWES_Tarea_5/index.php/articulo?id=<?php echo $articulo["id"] ?>"></a>
        </li> 
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
   <?php endblock() ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Además, me he dado cuenta de que los href de este html tampoco salen por pantalla :/

Actualización: solucionados los problemas de las imágenes y de los enlaces gracias a @masterguru. Sin embargo, tengo otro problema de nuevo con las rutas.
Me explico:
Una vez pinchas en el enlace del código anterior, abres una página en la que aparecen más detalles del artículo en cuestión. Sin embargo, oh sorpresa, la imagen del artículo no aparece en esta nueva página. Añado el código

```
    <?php include "base.php" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<body>
    <h3>Detalles artículo</h3>
    <?php startblock("plantilla") ?>
    <!--Muestra una lista de artículos-->    
    Detalles artículo: <?php echo $detalles["id"] ?>
    <img width="400" height="400" src="<?php echo "imagenes/" .$detalles["a_imagen"] ?> "/>
    <h2><?php echo $detalles["titulo"] ?></h2>

    <?php endblock() ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Estas poniendo dos veces la carpeta imagenes con esto: `echo "imagenes/" .$articulo["a_imagen"]` porque luego el **a_imagen** dices que sigue siendo esto: `"a_imagen" => "imagenes/azul.jpg"`... por lo tanto la url final te queda así:  `imagenes/imagenes/azul.jpg` la cual no está bien supongo

Comment: Efectivamente estaba la carpeta imagenes repetida. Sin embargo, sigo sin poder visualizar los "a" de los artículos

Comment: La segunda opción: dominio.com/carpeta/index.php

Comment: De nuevo en la segunda opción. Sin embargo, las imágenes no tienen relación con los enlaces, es decir, el enlace al artículo específico debería aparecer debajo de la foto

Comment: Ah, jolin, perdona, seguia empecinado con las imagenes.. eso quiere decir que ya te salen, claro... a ver, lo del `<a>` no te sale porque no pones nada entre `<a>` y `</a>`, tan solo atributos dentro de `<a>`... para que salga algo debes poner contenido entre ambos tags de ese elemento, es decir, `<a href="url">url</a>` o bien `<a href="url">Texto significativo de enlace</a>`

Comment: He borrado comentarios porque sino nos mandan a un chat y no quiero eso. En cuanto a las imágenes he puesto una respuesta **definitiva** y en cuanto a lo de la `<a>` no lo pongo en la respuesta porque no creo que haga falta, espero que ya lo hayas entendido.

Comment: Efectivamente el problema con los enlaces estaba ahí. Sin embargo, ahora vuelvo a tener un problema con las imágenes dentro de esos enlaces. He editado la pregunta para añadir el código de la nueva página

Comment: Estas repitiendo el error de antes pero en la nueva página:  `<?php echo "imagenes/" .$detalles["a_imagen"] ?>`... intenta leerte mi respuesta y aplicarla y así lo solucionarás de una vez por todas y para siempre, y solo deberas preocuparte de modificar un único archivo si las imagenes cambian de ruta

Comment: Ya está solucionado. El problema era la posición relativa de los archivos, que no estaban en el mismo directorio, por lo que la referencia a la imagen tenía que ser distinta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debido a la **diversidad de posibles escenarios al mostrar páginas web generadas dinámicamente con PHP en formato HTML**, vamos a intentar aplicar **la solución definitiva** a este tipo de problemas, la cual **implica utilizar un archivo de configuración** que será **incluído en todos los archivos PHP** que necesiten calcular rutas de imágenes.

Esta solución pasa por utilizar **rutas absolutas**, con las limitaciones que esto implica, una de las cuales, la más importante, es que **si movemos la carpeta de imágenes de sitio o bien toda la estructura de árbol de directorios de la web, deberemos modificar de nuevo la ruta absoluta** de las imágenes.  Pero **lo vamos a poner sólo en un único sitio**, que será **un archivo de configuración que será incuído en todos los PHP** que lo necesiten.

Para ello creamos un nuevo archivo de configuración, o bien aprovechamos alguno que ya estemos usando (por ejemplo el de la conexión a base de datos) y agregamos un [define()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.define.php) de este modo:

```
define('RUTA_IMAGENES','/ruta/absoluta/a/la/carpeta/de/las/imagenes');
```

donde:

- **RUTA_IMAGENES** es el nombre de la constante a utilizar después dentro de los PHP que representa la ruta absoluta a las imágenes en nuestra web
- **/ruta/absoluta/a/la/carpeta/de/las/imagenes** es, tal como su nombre indica, la **ruta absoluta** (empezando por `/` que identifica el directorio raíz de nuestro dominio, que se puede averiguar mediante un `echo $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];`) hasta la carpeta de las imágenes.

Luego, suponiendo que llamamos a este archivo **config.php** y que lo hemos puesto en la carpeta raíz del dominio, en cada archivo PHP vamos a incluir dicho archivo de configuración mediante un [include()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.include.php) de este modo al principio de cada PHP:

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/config.php');
```

Y para terminar, cuando llamemos a las imágenes, tan solo deberemos usar su nombre precedido de la constante RUTA_IMAGENES de este modo:

```
$imagen = RUTA_IMAGENES.'/azul.png';
```

O en tu caso concreto seria así:

```
<?php echo RUTA_IMAGENES. "/" .$articulo["a_imagen"] ?>
```

pero ten en cuenta, en este caso, que cuando definas la `a_imagen`, debes ponerla así:

```
"a_imagen" => "catan.jpg"
```

Si se necesitan diversas rutas segun sea conveniente para las imágenes, como una para las fotos de perfil, otra para los productos, etc... entonces hay que agregas más constantes y usarlas para cada caso:

```
define('RUTA_IMAGENES','/ruta/absoluta/a/la/carpeta/de/las/imagenes');
define('RUTA_IMAGENES_PERFILES','/ruta/absoluta/a/la/carpeta/de/las/imagenes/de/los/perfiles');
define('RUTA_IMAGENES_PRODUCTOS','/ruta/absoluta/a/la/carpeta/de/las/imagenes/de/los/productos');
```

y luego usarlos en consecuencia en cada caso, tal como he explicado antes.