# Include header y footer

Tags: php, style

Tengo una pagina con mas de 250 paginas, en las cuales me serviría utilizar el include y colocar dicho header y footer.

El punto es el siguiente, tengo dicho header y footer en la pagina, en el index me cargan perfecto, con su style, imagenes y todo en su lugar, a la hora de entrar a la carpeta de "categorías" y cargar dicho header y footer me carga solo el codigo html y no con su style ni imagenes (Cosa que esta incluido dentro del header y el footer original que estoy llamando).

La idea/pregunta es se puede logar que con solo tener un header y un footer se llegue a cargar en diferentes carpetas llamándolo con el include o requiere?

Paso parte del codigo del header y sus ubicaciones y como lo estoy llamando...

Index que carga perfecto

Index
Skin (Carpeta contenedora)(header.php / footer.php)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es">
    
        <?php include ("Skin/header.php") ?>
        <?php include ("Skin/categoria.php") ?>
        
        <?php include ("Skin/nuevos.php") ?>   
        <?php include ("Skin/destacados.php") ?>   
            
            <p class="VM"><a href="Categorias/Categorias">Ver todas las categorias</a></p>
    
        <?php include ("Skin/carrucel.php") ?>
        
        <?php include ("Skin/footer.php") ?>
    
    
        </body>
    </html>
```

Aquí empieza el problema

El section esta vacio para no poner código de mas....

El punto es que ahora tomo el archivo header.php y footer.php de la misma carpeta y no carga su style ni imagenes (Cosa que esta escrito dentro del mismo)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    
    <?php include '../Skin/header.php';?> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
       
    
<!-- /HEADER -->

        <!-- SECTION -->
        <div class="section">
            <!-- container -->
        </div>
        <!-- /SECTION -->
<br><br>
        
<!--/Sub Footer-->
    <?php include '../Skin/footer.php';?> 
    
        <!-- jQuery Plugins -->
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/slick.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/nouislider.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.zoom.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Archivo header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="keywords" content="TorniShop, TruckShop, Repuestos, Tornilleria, Ferreteria industrial, Repuesto camiones"/>
  
  <!-- EVITAR CACHE -->
  <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
  <meta http-equiv="Last-Modified" content="0">
  <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, mustrevalidate">
  <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
   <!-- EVITAR CACHE -->
   
  <title>TorniShop | TruckShop, Repuestos, Tornilleria, Ferreteria industrial, Repuesto camiones</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="img/icon/Ts.png">

        <!-- Google font -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,500,700" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- jQuery Plugins -->
        <script src="js/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        
        <!-- Font Awesome Icon -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link href="https://file.myfontastic.com/9FNtGvFZYgKtdCoP5J8xHf/icons.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Custom stlylesheet -->

        <link href="css/Bootstrap/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/Bootstrap/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/Bootstrap/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/buscar.js"></script>
       
        <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
        <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-176776839-1"></script>
        <script>
          window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
          function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
          gtag('js', new Date());

          gtag('config', 'UA-176776839-1');
        </script>
   
   
    </head>
    <body id="fix">    

        <!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
        <noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-PDG96ZK"
        height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
        <!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
    

    <header class="headerr">
        <div class="containerM">
        <div class="btn-menu1">
            <label class="btn-label" for="btn-menu1">☰</label>
        </div>
            <div class="logo">
                <h1><a href="index"><img src="img/icon/Ts.png" alt=""></a></h1>
            </div>
       
                        <div class="iconB" id="iconB"></div>  
        <div>
                   
            <nav class="menuu">
                <a href="index" class="active">Home</a>
                <a href="Categorias/Categorias">Categorias</a>
                <a href="Contacto/contacto">Contacto</a>
                <a href="Catalogo/Solicitud-Cat">Catalogo</a>
                <a id="action-list-1" href="https://www.google.com/maps/dir//TORNISHOP+repuestos+-+tornilleria+-+ferreteria+industrial/data=!4m8!4m7!1m0!1m5!1m1!1s0x95a1d2a2c4acb877:0x273ef70e59ff68a5!2m2!1d-56.223701899999995!2d-34.7340471" target="_blank" data-tracking-element-type="5" jslog="// LINT.IfChange(PostCTAType)56039; track:impression,click" itemprop="hasMap" data-enable-ga="true" data-ga-prefix="action-list">Cómo llegar</a>
            </nav>
        </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    
    <div class="capa"></div>
<!--    --------------->
<input type="checkbox" id="btn-menu1">
<div class="container-menu1">
    <div class="cont-menu1">
        <nav class="MDesp">
            <a href="index" class="activee">Home</a>
            <a href="Categorias/Categorias">Categorias</a>
            <a href="Contacto/contacto">Contacto</a>
            <a href="Catalogo/Solicitud-Cat">Catalogo</a>
            <a id="action-list-2" href="https://www.google.com/maps/dir//TORNISHOP+repuestos+-+tornilleria+-+ferreteria+industrial/data=!4m8!4m7!1m0!1m5!1m1!1s0x95a1d2a2c4acb877:0x273ef70e59ff68a5!2m2!1d-56.223701899999995!2d-34.7340471" target="_blank" data-tracking-element-type="5" jslog="// LINT.IfChange(PostCTAType)56039; track:impression,click" itemprop="hasMap" data-enable-ga="true" data-ga-prefix="action-list">Cómo llegar</a>
        </nav>
        <label class="btn-label" for="btn-menu1">✖️</label>
    </div>
</div>

       
        <div class="searchh" id="searchh" >
          <div class="inputFB">
           <input class="inputB" type="text" name="termino" id="termino" placeholder="Buscar por OEM / Codigo / Nombre" aria-label="Search">
          </div>
       </div>
               
               <script>
                   
                   
                     $(document).ready(function(){
                           Act1(); 
                           Act2(); 

                      });
                   
                        function Act1(){
                            $('#iconB').on('click', function(event) {
                                $('#iconB').toggleClass('activa');
                                $('#searchh').toggleClass('activo');
                                $('#bgg').toggleClass('bggA');
                                $('#fix').toggleClass('fix');
                                $('#termino').toggle('show');
                                $('#TablaB').toggle('show');
                                $('#termino').val('');
                            });
                        };
                   
                            $(document).keyup(function(e){
                                if(e.which==27) {
                                    $('.iconB.activa').click();
                                }
                       })
                        
                        function Act2(){
                            $('#clear').on('click', function(event) {
                                $('#iconB').toggleClass('activo');
                            });
                        };
                        
                   
                   </script>
       
        <div class="bgg" id="bgg"></div>
    
        <div class="TablaB" id="TablaB">

            <section class="content-area">
                <div class="table-area" id="tabla_resultados">

                </div>
            </section>

               
        </div>
   
    <!--/Torni-->
    
    <div class="torni">
        <img src="img/boddy/Boddy-Pagina2.jpg" alt="Torni" class="torniS">
    </div>        

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Te estas haciendo un lio con las rutas absolutas y relativas. Seguramente dentro del `header.php` (que no has puesto en la pregunta) estás usando rutas relativas, y al invocarlo desde un subdirectorio distinto del que contiene el index.php que sí funciona, esas rutas se quedan mal puestas. Pásate a las rutas absolutas en ese `header.php` para que eso no ocurra, o bien en toda tu web, pues tal como lo estas estructurando te puede pasar a menudo en cualquier sitio donde estes usando las rutas relativas dentro de tu código.

Comment: Okey, edito y agrego el archivo header.php para que lo puedan ver

Comment: Lo que decia, el header.php lo tienes lleno de referencias relativas, y cuando ese archivo lo incluyes en una ruta que no es la raiz entonces se pierden. La solución es poner la barra inicial a todas ellas, que apunta a la raiz de la web, para que sea desde donde sea que se llame a ese archivo, siempre este apuntando correctamente a sus enlaces, imagenes, archivos css, js, etc.  Es decir, por ejemplo, donde pone esto: `href="css/Bootstrap/bootstrap.css"` pon esto: `href="/css/Bootstrap/bootstrap.css"` con una barra inclinada `/` al principio.

Comment: Bien, al hacer eso no me lo toma el ni desde el index, ya lo había intentado

Comment: Eso será porque tu ruta no empieza en la raiz del dominio... es decir, tu index.php no está en `http://www.midominio.com/index.php` sino que quizás lo tienes en una carpeta, por ejemplo:  `http://www.midominio.com/carpeta/index.php` ... con lo cual, lo dicho antes lo debes cambiar de `/` a `/carpeta/` (o si la ruta es más larga pues tambien lo pones `/carpeta/carpeta/carpeta/etc/`

Comment: Ejemplo tengo la Ruta inicial del archivo index, dentro de una carpeta X alojo lo que son los header.php y de mas, a la ruta de los mismos le agregue "/css/style.css" y aun asi es cuando desde el idex no los toma

Comment: Mírate esta respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/526492/problema-con-rutas-relativas-en-php/526622#526622 a ver si te te sirve hacerlo de ese modo

Comment: [Aqui tienes otra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/525881/cargar-recursos-desde-otra-subcarpeta-php/525899#525899) de mis respuestas sobre este tema, y [aquí otra más](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/522761/especificar-un-ruta-de-archivo-txt-en-php/522771#522771)... todas van a parar a los mismo o cosas similares a lo que te ocurre

Comment: Puedes poner lo de la ruta de las carpetas como respuesta, así la marco como aceptada y te puntúa y se cierra la pregunta

Comment: No es por la puntuación, aunque tampoco la desprecio, pero acabo de poner  la respuesta para que la pregunta no quede pendiente y porque segun parece ya lo tienes claro y arreglado, y supongo que mi información de los comentarios ha colaborado en ello. Gracias y saludos!

Comment: Si exactamente, gracias a tu ayuda pude resolver el conflicto que tenia con la carga de los archivos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según parece, tal como el OP ha indicado en los comentarios, **sus archivos parten de una subcarpeta del dominio** y no de la raíz, por lo tanto, para solucionarlo usando **rutas absolutas** debe usar esa subcarpeta en lugar de la raíz del dominio para apuntar correctamente a sus archivos de forma inequívoca.

Es decir, su index.php no está en:

```
http://www.midominio.com/index.php
```

sino que lo tiene en una carpeta, por ejemplo:

```
http://www.midominio.com/carpeta/index.php
```

con lo cual, en su archivo header.php (y cualquier otro que sea incluido usando rutas relativas) ha optado por modificar sus rutas relativas por absolutas, **pero** partiendo de esa carpeta.

Por ejemplo, ahora tiene así (**ruta relativa**) uno de sus enlaces del **header.php**:

```html
<script src="js/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

pues finalmente debe ponerlo así para que funcione bien en sus diversos include desde cualquier carpeta del dominio:

```html
<script src="/carpeta/js/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

donde:

- la primera barra inclinada `/` apunta a la raíz de su dominio
- y el texto `carpeta/` representa el nombre de carpeta desde donde van a incluirse el resto de archivos del header.php.

Este tipo de pregunta ya la habia respondido en varias ocasiones con distintos matices en las siguientes respuestas:

- [Cargar recursos desde otra subcarpeta PHP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/525881/cargar-recursos-desde-otra-subcarpeta-php/525899#525899)
- [Problema con rutas relativas en PHP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/526492/problema-con-rutas-relativas-en-php/526622#526622)
- [Especificar un ruta de archivo .txt en php](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/522761/especificar-un-ruta-de-archivo-txt-en-php/522771#522771)

En cada una de ellas he dado diversidad de información que puede ayudar a comprender el típico problema de las rutas que no funcionan en los diversos escenarios que se pueden dar en un proyecto web.